# Javascript files are not getting loaded in rails production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thorax.js

My application is running on `rails-4.1.2` and `thorax.js` as front-end **javascript** framework. When I added `new thorax.js route` and pages to my application, the application dashboard **page is not getting loaded**. And I have no errors in production log.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does your browser's development tools' network panel say is happening? Are you getting 404? Are you getting wrong content? Is there something in your browser's console? Is your app keeping a production log serverside? What is it configured to track, and what does it contain? What happens when you increase log level for production? How are you serving your thorax.js - is it from the public directory? Are you using an asset pipeline, and if so are your assets compiled?

Comment: Yes my assets are getting compiled. I am getting response script in my browser console with  src=/assets/application-d4e050cf39dcb5411e1ea62f18958933.js but the page is not getting loaded. I am not getting any 404 error. The production log: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (14.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (4.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 59ms (Views: 22.0ms)

Comment: I am getting 304 GET not modified error in the browser console. Is it has any thing to do with?

Comment: 304 means the content is the same and the browser can get it from the cache (and it's not normally regarded as "error"). So if you surf over there, what do you get? Is your JS rendered? If you put in a `console.log("foo")` at the top of your JS, is it being executed? You need to diagnose what is not working: sending, loading, or execution. I gave you some nice questions to ask your environment, but unfortunately you'll have to do the legwork.

Comment: You're going to have to give us a little more to go on. Please paste (using jsfiddle, GitHub gist, or in here if you can keep it tight and tidy) the *relevant* parts of your app, describe what's actually happening (is the HTML being loaded? is the JS being loaded? is there a JS error in the console?), and what you're doing to make this happen (What exactly is the URL for your Thorax route? How are you executing it?)